# SQL: order by calculated rate between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, sql-order-by

I might be confusing syntax from other languages with SQL and that's why this isn't working, my subquery is definitely incorrect.

Having the following 2 tables:

```
TEST_RESULTS
Student_ID Test_ID Test_Result
    A1       234       90  
    B2       234       80  
    C3       345       85
    D4       234       95
    A1       345       95
    C3       456       95


TEST_DESCRIPTION 
Test_ID  Test_Description Passing_Score
  234         Test A            85
  345         Test B            90
  456         Test C            95
```

I want to calculate the rate of passing for each test and sort by it.

The output I am looking for:

```
Test_ID   Test_Description  students_taking students_passing   rate
456             Test C         1                1               1
234             Test A         3                2               0.666666667
345             Test B         2                1               0.5
```

This is my query

```
SELECT td.Test_ID, td.Test_Description, COUNT(tr.Student_ID) as 
students_taking, students_passing, students_passing/students_taking as rate
FROM 
(SELECT td.Test_ID, td.Test_Description, COUNT(tr.Student_ID) as 
students_passing
FROM TEST_RESULTS tr
JOIN TEST_DESCRIPTION td
on tr.Test_ID = td.Test_ID
WHERE tr.Test_Result > td.)
GROUP BY td.Test_ID, td.Test_Description
ORDER BY rate DESC, td.Test_ID, td.Test_Description
```

My select from select is wrong, because I am getting no results for this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using CTE, LEFT JOIN for getting the desired result.
Try this query --

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        TD.TEST_ID,
        TEST_DESCRIPTION,
        COUNT(TR.STUDENT_ID) AS STUDENTS_TAKING,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN TR.TEST_RESULT >= TD.PASSING_SCORES THEN 
            TR.STUDENT_ID END) AS STUDENTS_PASSING
    FROM TEST_DESCRIPTION TD
    LEFT JOIN TEST_RESULTS TR
    ON TD.TEST_ID = TR.TEST_ID
    GROUP BY TD.TEST_ID,
        TEST_DESCRIPTION
)
SELECT 
    TEST_ID,
    TEST_DESCRIPTION,
    STUDENTS_TAKING,
    STUDENTS_PASSING,
    STUDENTS_PASSING / CONVERT (DECIMAL(4,2),STUDENTS_TAKING) AS RATE
FROM CTE
ORDER BY TEST_DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: thank you very much - what is the benefit of using CTE over the other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT td.Test_ID, td.Test_Description,
    students_taking  = counts.students_taking,
    students_passing = counts.students_passing,
    rate             = counts.rate
FROM TEST_DESCRIPTION td 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 
        students_taking    = COUNT(1),
        students_passing   = COUNT(CASE WHEN tr.Test_Result > td.Passing_score THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
        rate               = IIF(COUNT(1) <> 0, COUNT(CASE WHEN tr.Test_Result > td.Passing_score THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS FLOAT), 0)
    FROM TEST_RESULTS tr
    WHERE tr.Test_ID = td.Test_ID
) counts
ORDER BY counts.rate DESC, td.Test_ID
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand the tr in the second last row after the bracket

Comment: It was an alias, I've renamed it to `counts`

Answer (score 1):

Please check below query-

```
SELECT TD.TEST_ID,
TD.TEST_DESCRIPTION,
STUDENT_TAKING,
STUDENT_PASSING,
RATE 
FROM TEST_DESCRIPTION TD,
  (SELECT TR.TEST_ID,COUNT(TR.STUDENT_ID) "STUDENT_TAKING",
  COUNT(CASE WHEN TEST_RESULT>=PASSING_SCORE THEN STUDENT_ID END) STUDENT_PASSING,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(COUNT(CASE WHEN TEST_RESULT>=PASSING_SCORE THEN STUDENT_ID END)/COUNT(TR.STUDENT_ID),'9999.99')) RATE
  FROM TEST_RESULTS TR,TEST_DESCRIPTION TD 
  WHERE TR.TEST_ID=TD.TEST_ID
  GROUP  BY TR.TEST_ID)SUB
  WHERE SUB.TEST_ID=TD.TEST_ID ORDER BY RATE DESC;
```